# when i use get_userdata for session it gives Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1561454057 ) but when i use userdata it gives empty

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to get the the user id of the current session in another after redirecting but it shows empty value. I'm using php 7.1.23 and ci 3.1.10.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$user_id);
            return redirect('Admin/Admin_dashboard');

$user_id = $this->session->get_userdata('user_id');
            print_r($user_id); exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This --

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$user_id);
            return redirect('Admin/Admin_dashboard');

$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
            print_r($user_id); 
            exit;
```

You have use this $this->session->userdata('user_id');

Answer (score 0):

The `Session` method `get_userdata()` does not accept an argument so I'm kind of surprised that your use does not throw an error. i.e.

```
$this->session->get_userdata('user_id'); //should throw an error`
```

`$this->session->get_userdata()` returns the whole `$_SESSION` array.

`$this->session->userdata($key)` returns `$_SESSION[$key]` if the key exists, or NULL if it does not.

The `userdata()` method exists only for backward compatibility. The recommended way to get a single item from `session` is to use this syntax.

```
$user_id = $this->session->user_id;
```

The above will set `$user_id` to `$_SESSION ['user_id']` if the key 'user_id' exists, or NULL if it does not. It will also return an empty array if `$_SESSION` does not exist which is an indication that `session` has not been started. However, because you see `__ci_last_regenerate` we know that `session` is running.

The other possible reason for the empty array could be that you do not have `session` configured correctly which could result in session data not being stored and/or retrieved.